# What quantity of neutron radiation could a water-filled inflatable mattress functionally negate?

Tags: physics, water, radiation, nuclear-weapons, radioactivity

I have a character who's a paranoid lunatic that's convinced that a nuclear war is about to break out. As a result of this, they've pumped several inflatable mattresses - you know, the type used for camping - full of water and used bungee cords to hang them in front of their windows; that way, if a nuclear attack catches them off-guard (i.e. outside their saferoom), the neutron radiation doesn't effect them as badly, since it has to go through water first.

Let's say that they're all [this model](https://www.target.com/p/intex-premium-durabeam-10-34-twin-air-mattress/-/A-79812927?ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&fndsrc=tmnv&DFA=71700000086272229&CPNG=PLA_DVM%2Ba064R000011uW1HQAU-Intex_LaborDay_FY21_Solo_Flight&adgroup=PLA_Intex_LaborDay&LID=700000001393753pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9033829&gclid=Cj0KCQjwm9yJBhDTARIsABKIcGaD69RLErijSmvynTfS03opsX7TT52WgnXv5LJuAs6Te43-e6mX8ZoaApnJEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) - i.e. roughly ten inches thick.

What quantity of neutron radiation, in terms of sieverts, can ten inches of water functionally negate?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly but I'd like to add that boric acid dissolved in water drastically improves it's neutron radiation shielding capabilities. If your mattress can handle the acid is another question however...

Comment: @RancidCrab Well, this character will try that, then. Rationality is for the sane.

Comment: Why not sand instead of water?

Comment: Water is heavy...an air mattress (or even a waterbed mattress hung vertically while filled) will almost certainly burst, and you'll need more than bungee cords to hang them up if they didn't. Shielding the windows isn't enough...if the walls provided good enough shielding, he could just cover the windows with some plywood and drywall sheets. Finally, it's trying to solve the wrong problem. If you can survive the thermal and blast effects of a strategic nuke, neutrons aren't a worry. It's radioactive fallout you need to be concerned about, not direct neutron radiation.

Comment: @SteroidSandwich  having similar mass particles works best to absorb the energy from neutrons. The most similar mass  is a proton which water has lots of.  hydrocarbons such as paraffin wax would also be good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to an article about "[Neutron Shielding Materials](https://www.eichrom.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/neutron-attenuation-white-paper-by-d-m-rev-2-1.pdf)", the half-thickness (thickness that absorbs half the radiation) of water against neutrons is 5.4 cm (page 8). 10 inches ~ 25 cm, so a water-filled mattress this thick would actually absorb 96% of incoming neutrons.

A problem may be that such a mattress that ia 2 m long and 1 m wide would weigh half a ton filled with water. I doubt many bungee cords could hold this weight.

Another problem is that the absorbed neutrons will make the water radioactive as the hydrogen atoms will turn into deuterium and tritium, of which the latter in particular is radioactive with a half-life of 12.32 years. The emitted radiation is low-energy beta radiation, which is stopped by the skin, but could be dangerous is the water is ingested or inhaled as water vapour.

Answer (score 2):

From this paper https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1698304

> Threshold detectors (In115, Ag107, and C12) were used to determine the relative intensities of neutrons at various distances inside a large water tank. Neutrons with energies up to 30 Mev were produced by (d, n) reactions. At distances in the water >20 cm the ``half‐thickness'' of water was found to be almost independent of neutron energy (about 8 cm).

After 20 cm of water it sounds like 8 cm are enough to half the dose irrespectively of their energy.

Comment: Can't read science, illiterate here, does it say anything about salt water?

Comment: @SteroidSandwich: I doubt that matters, since the main absorption is done by the hydrogen in the water.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen got it, thanks